# How i get the image in the same row of selected radio button?

Tags: android, radio-button, imageview, adapter

I have custom list and each row contains image ,text view and radiobutton not radio group.
i select only one radiobutton . i want to get the image that is in the same row of the selected radiobutton. Then i set the background with this image
help me please.

```
//rowadapter
public class rowadapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private final Activity context;
int layoutResourceId;    
private final String[] web;
private final Integer[] imageId;
int selectedPosition = -1;
SharedPreferences sharedPref;

public rowadapter(Activity context,String[] web, Integer[] imageId) {
    super(context,R.layout.item_listview, web);
    this.context = context;
    this.web = web;
    this.imageId = imageId;
     sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("position",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

}
public View getView(final int position, View row, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
    backgroundholder holder = null;
    View rowView=row;

        rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_listview, null, true);

        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        txtTitle.setText(web[position]);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
        holder = new backgroundholder();    
        holder.radiobutton = (RadioButton)rowView.findViewById(R.id.radiobutton);
        holder.radiobutton.setChecked(position == selectedPosition);
        holder.radiobutton.setTag(position);
        int checkedpos=sharedPref.getInt("position",-1);
        if(checkedpos==position)
        {
           holder.radiobutton.setChecked(true);
        }


        holder.radiobutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {     
        public void onClick(View view)
              {
                  selectedPosition = (Integer)view.getTag();
                   RadioButton radio = (RadioButton)view;
                   if(radio.isChecked())
                   {
                   Editor editor=sharedPref.edit();
                   editor.putInt("position", selectedPosition);
                   editor.commit();
                   }
                   Intent i=new Intent(getContext(), Preferences.class);
                   context.startActivity(i);
                  notifyDataSetInvalidated();

              }

          });        

   return rowView;


}
static class backgroundholder
{

    RadioButton radiobutton;
}

}
//object class
import android.widget.RadioButton;


public class Item {
String txt;
Integer drawable;
RadioButton radiobutton;
boolean checked;
public Item(String txt,Integer drawable,RadioButton radiobutton)
{
this.txt=txt;
this.drawable=drawable;
this.radiobutton=radiobutton;
}

public String gettxt()
{
return txt;

}
public Integer getInteger()
{
return drawable;

 }

public boolean ischecked()
{
return checked;

 }
 public void setchecked(boolean checked)
{
this.checked=checked;
 }
 }
```

Comment: take linear layout `horizontal` and add all in one line

Comment: i don`t understand the answer ..

Comment: which layout are you using in XML file? post xml file here

Comment: no the background not xml file ... i want first to get the image then i can set the background .. the problem now is to get the image from the same row of the selected radio button

Answer (score 0):

if you know what is the textview value of that row, you can use this method:

```
if (listview.getItemAtPosition(position).toString() == "item 1") {
imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.drawable1)
} else if (listview.getItemAtPosition(position).toString() == "item 2") {
imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.drawable2)
}
```

Edit:
now I read your question once again and find out that you want to change the background by clicking each of the listview items. is that correct?

for that you don't need getview at all.

first you should implement listview onItemClick and then base on what is the position of that selected row, change the background.

something like this:

in your oncreat:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {

            if (listview.getItemAtPosition(position).toString() == "item 1") {
              //put your change background code here
             } else if (listview.getItemAtPosition(position).toString() == "item 2") {
              //put your change background code here
}
        }
    });
```

for changing background, you can use this code:

```
layout.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.drawable));
```

Comment: yes i can get the textview value .. but i dont know where i write this part ??

Comment: @user3631823 in your getView() method. Under 'txtTitle.setText(web[position]);'

Comment: it doesnt work ... my list identified in other activity and i make holder holds the list view ..but it doesnt work too.

Comment: hint : i draw on canvas

Comment: @user3631823 that's your choice for how to change the Background. if my answer helped you in finding the selected row, please accept it.